# How to make file name unique after each angular build?

Tags: angular

I have setup my build command as `ng build --output-hashing=all` to avoid caching, but then I find out what after every build the name of main bundle is the same i.e. main.6d9fbe532c4c365c1cdf.bundle.js.

How to make file name unique after each build?

Comment: You cannot. Maybe the hansl's answer will help : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3769

Comment: In my understanding main.6d9fbe532c4c365c1cdf.bundle.js is cached, so after deploy I cannot be sure what new bundle is used by the browser.

Comment: Put a version number on your app and check it?

Comment: Ok, I understood the trick. The file name is different if .js file is changed.